# How to preload MongoDB document only once programatically on node server using mongoose

Tags: angularjs, node.js, typescript, express

How to `preload` some data in the `MongoDB` using `mongoose` on `node` server.
I want to add some default data/document in collection of `MongoDB`.
Is it possible to add the data in collection after creating schema?
Through grammatically.

Comment: You can, but it's better to do this as a separate script that you explicitly call when you need it, rather than runingtqueries Everytime the app starts whether or not it's needed.

Comment: It is a design choice which depends on the nature of your app and how it will be used, I prefer to run it automatically because my app doesn't run without a few key documents and its quicker for my team this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my project, I have this code to bootstrap my mongodb when my app runs to populate the database.

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

function _bootstrapDbModel(schemaName, schema, collectionName) {
  const model = mongoose.model(schemaName, schema, collectionName);
  // if there is not data in the collection, populate it
  model.count().then((count) => {
    if (count === 0) {
      // load prdefined data
      // which I prepare and named according to my collection name
      const data = require(`../data/${collectionName}`);
      model.insertMany(data.documents).then((results) => {
        _.map(results, (result) => { console.log(`Inserted _id:${result._id} into ${collectionName}`) });
      });
    }
  });
```

This is how my data look like

```
const ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;

exports.documents = [
  {
    _id: ObjectId('54d19680b51c15260b944fd5'),
    email: 'myemail@company.com',
    ....
  }
];
```

Comment: Hi Thanks neo, do i have to call this method _bootstrapDbModel or it will be auto called.

Comment: You will call it after connection is successful.

Comment: Thanks Neo It help me i will up vote please do edit the above post and do this changes        logger.info(collectionName+' collection is empty. Loading default data...');         const data = require('../data/'+collectionName);         logger.info('Inserted _id:'+result._id +'into '+collectionName);         first ` is not valid and so only it was not working for me

Comment: Oops, my bad. I copied this sample from my project which had a global `logger`

Comment: model.insertMany(data.documents)  ,data.documents mean your json file is having the structure as {documents:[{ your :data},{your :data}]}  if you have kept the data in the json file as array only like this  [{ your :data},{your :data}] then only pass data in the method like this  model.insertMany(data)  in above code